# visual studio code restructured text extension cannot find linter

Tags: visual-studio-code, restructuredtext, vscode-extensions

I'm new to VS Code and can't figure this out. I'm attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/master/docs/sphinx.md).

I'm getting this message:

> Cannot lint c:\sphinxtest\index.rst. The executable was not found. Use the 'restructuredtext.executablePath' setting to configure the location of the executable

My VSC preferences file looks like this:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",

    "restructuredtext.linter.executablePath": "%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Scripts\restructuredtext-lint"
}
```

I have confirmed that `restructuredtext-lint.exe` is located at the path shown above. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have also confirmed that the `Anaconda3\Scripts` directory is in my system path, so `restructuredtext-lint` should be found by the extension using the default setting anyway, yet it is not. However when I type `restructuredtext-lint` at the command line, the script is found as expected.

Comment: Sadly you did not open the issue on GitHub, while I don't monitor Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem and I think it is a bug of the vscode restructured extension.

A quick and dirty workaround that works for me consists of patching the file `rstLinter.js` with a single line comment:

`$VSCODE_EXTENSION_DIR/lextudio.restructuredtext-37.0.0/out/features/rstLinter.js`

`$VSCODE_EXTENSION_DIR` is the vscode extension directory, on Linux for example is located at `~/.vscode/extensions`

```
loadConfiguration() {
    let section = vscode_1.workspace.getConfiguration(this.languageId);
    if (!section)
        return;
    var module = [];
    // comment the following line
    //var python = vscode_1.workspace.getConfiguration("python").get("pythonPath", null);
    // add this line
    var python = null;
```

UPDATE

The above ugly patch works in any case because the lint executable is then selected from `linter.executablePath.restructuredtext-lint` setting.

Otherwise first restructured plugin choice is to get python executable from `python.pythonPath` setting:

For example, in my case python executable (`python.pythonPath` setting) was set to `${workspaceRoot}/nais/bin/python` in Workspace Setting.

Apparently the environment variable `$workspaceRoot` is not substituted before spawning the process and this cause a NOENT error.

The message in the error bar points in the wrong direction, check the python path before applying the patch, this may resolve the problem.

Comment: uggggghhhh workarounds. i ended up ditching vscode altogether and downloading Pycharm.

Comment: I agree, it's ugghh ... after some more investigation I updated my answer, for a possible solution without applying the "dirty" patch

Comment: There were issues in this area, but I never received reports with enough background, until this one https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/issues/72 So I believe release 45.0.0 and above should work better. Again, next time please go to GitHub and report the issues you meet. I don't monitor Stack Overflow for questions (as I assume most users go to GitHub by default), so responses here will be slow.

Comment: @LexLi Apologies for that- I'm not a developer by training and didn't even know how to use GitHub until about six months ago. I think I was just assuming I was doing something wrong and didn't want to bother anyone with my stupidity. I'll be more proactive in the future.